# What does ebtables.service do?

Tags: debian, firewalld

On Fedora, the `firewalld` package requires `ebtables`.  Installing `firewalld` on Debian also installs `ebtables` by default, although it is a recommendation and not a hard requirement.

Fedora does not enable all services by default.  It enables the systemd service for `firewalld`, but not `ebtables`.

Debian enables all services by default.  So it enables the systemd service for both `firewalld` and `ebtables`.

- What does `ebtables.service` do?
- Assume I am only interested in the features of `firewalld` specifically.  Then does enabling `ebtables.service` do anything useful?

  - Would disabling `ebtables.service` on Debian disable any feature of `firewalld`?
  - Does enabling `ebtables.service` on Fedora enable any feature of `firewalld`?
  - Is there any possible conflict between `ebtables.service` and `firewalld.service`?
- What does `firewalld` use `ebtables` for?

### Software versions

- Debian: 9

  - firewalld: 0.4.4.2-1
  - ebtables: 2.0.10.4-3.5+b1
- Fedora: 28

  - firewalld: 0.5.5-1.fc28.noarch
  - ebtables: 2.0.10-25.fc28.x86_64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what `firewalld` uses `ebtables` for.

> Is there any possible conflict between ebtables.service and firewalld.service?

Yes.  `firewalld.service` is defined as `Conflicts=ebtables.service`.

I believe this works and provides the desired result, both during boot, and immediately after the install.  See: [systemd service A has `Conflicts=B`. Both A and B are enabled. Can you tell which service will be allowed to start at boot, if any, or is it random?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/491740/systemd-service-a-has-conflicts-b-both-a-and-b-are-enabled-can-you-tell-whic/491741#491741)

I find this potentially confusing.  I would consider explicitly disabling `ebtables.service`.

---

Comparing the `ebtables.service` on Debian 9 and Fedora 28, they work slightly differently.

They both have similar code, which can save ebtables rulesets when the service is stopped, and restore them when it is started.

On my Debian system, `ebtables.service` reads options from `/etc/default/ebtables`, which say to do *almost* nothing by default.  It does however clear the ebtables rulesets when stopped or restarted.

On my Fedora system, `ebtables.service` provides similar features.  There is an options file at `/etc/sysconfig/ebtables-config` which looks the same as the Debian one, but AFAICT it is *not* referenced by ebtables.service.  Instead, all the features are fully enabled once you enable `ebtables.service`.