# systemd service A has `Conflicts=B`. Both A and B are enabled. Can you tell which service will be allowed to start at boot, if any, or is it random?

Tags: systemd

Installing the `firewalld` package on Debian 9 also pulls in the `ebtables` package.  This adds two services to the system, `firewalld` and `ebtables`.  As usual, Debian enables both services.

`firewalld.service` is marked as `Conflicts=ebtables.service`.

What will happen with these two services when the system boots?  Can I tell which of the two will be allowed to run?  Or will neither be allowed to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If a unit A that conflicts with a unit B is scheduled to be started at the same time as B, the transaction will either fail (in case
>              both are required part of the transaction) or be modified to be fixed (in case one or both jobs are not a required part of the
>              transaction). In the latter case, the job that is not the required will be removed, or in case both are not required, the unit that
>              conflicts will be started and the unit that is conflicted is stopped.
>
> -- [man systemd.unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.unit.html)

In this case, both `firewalld.service` and `ebtables.service` are only `WantedBy=multi-user.target`, not `RequiredBy=`.

**Conclusion:** `firewalld.service` will be started, and `ebtables.service` will not.

---

This does not tell you what happens immediately when you install `firewalld`.  Fortunately it is the same result, because `ebtables` is installed first.  This ordering means that `ebtables.service` is started temporarily, but it is stopped again once `firewalld.service` is started:

> If a unit has a Conflicts= setting on another unit, starting the former will stop the latter and vice versa.